Built in webcam doesn't work - Acer Aspire A515-57G - Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
i have a problem with the webcam of my pc,
i alreday saw that other user made the same question for the ubuntu version 22 but those suggestions don't work for me. Can someone help?
this is what i tried so far with no success  Built in webcam doesn't work - Acer Aspire A515-57G
Here is my lsusb output (it detects the webcam):
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1532:0083 Razer USA, Ltd RC30-0315, Gaming Mouse [Basilisk X HyperSpeed]
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:8006 Microdia Dual Mode Camera (8006 VGA)
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0408:4033 Quanta Computer, Inc. ACER HD User Facing
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f3:0c4f Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help

Which programs did you try? did you try google test https://webcamtests.com/

@amar thanks for the suggestion, i tried with every program and i just got the message: "Could not find a web camera, however there are other media devices (like speakers or microphones). Most likely, this means that your webcam is not working properly or your browser cannot access it." I got this message basically with every program. And if i force the start i got the message: "NotFoundError: The object can not be found here.; DOMException."

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:8006 Microdia Dual Mode Camera (8006 VGA) https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/0C45/device/8006 and run sudo lsusb -v also usdb-devices in terminal

Solution from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2477627 does not work because patch is for different kernel version.
So, need to update patch for new kernel. For this, instead of downloading uvc_driver.c as described here https://github.com/Giuliano69/uvc_driver-for-Quanta-HD-User-Facing-0x0408-0x4035-/blob/main/compile_module.sh#L24, it is necessary to copy existing file uvc_driver.c and to add this block https://github.com/Giuliano69/uvc_driver-for-Quanta-HD-User-Facing-0x0408-0x4035-/blob/main/uvc_driver.c#L2469 (or previous, depending on your webcam version) to the corresponding place. After that, compile and install in the same way.
